# How do I store the Number found in multiple lines in a csv file

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a csv file that stores the following information on each line; name, phone number, class time, duration of the class. I am trying to store only the phone number from each line of the csv file into a list. I am currently trying to get it to work using regex, but if there are better suggestions, I am all ears. I am relatively new to coding python, so any other advice would be much appreciated.

'''

def get_numbers():

```
file = open("students.csv")
regex = r"(\d+)"
for row in file:
    if row:
        result = re.search(regex, row)
print(result[0])
```

'''

This is a sample of what each line in the csv file looks like:

James Example,611-544-3091,8:00pm,1hr

Carl Example,900-122-818,12:15pm,30 mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to do this.

### 1

Pandas offers a very elegant solution. You can read the csv file, and extract only the phone numbers. Here is how to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', names=['name', 'phone number', 'class time', 'duration'])
phno = df['Phone number'].tolist()
```

What this essentially does is, it takes your entire data and makes it into a table. Each line of your file corresponds to one row, and each entry in a line corresponds to a column entry. Once you make it into a table using the `read_csv` instruction, you can then extract any column. You require the 'Phone Number` column, thus you pick up that column using `df['Phone Number']` and convert it into a list.

### 2

If you do not want to use pandas, here is another method.

```
for row in file:
  phno = row.split(',')[1]
  print(phno)
  #or append it to some master list if you wish
```

Comment: Did not you forget the `csv` module from the standard library?

Comment: Oh yeah, definitely that too! I havent had much use for the ```csv``` module just by itself, hence that didnt pop up right away.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I used the code with pandas. I was wondering if you could explain what exactly the code does. I really would like to understand so I can use it for the future. Furthermore, do you know any resources where I can learn more about the uses of pandas and bumpy?

Comment: Hi @rod.hoda, I have edited my answer with an explanation. To learn more about pandas, you can check out their tutorials and get started on it. I would however suggest learning pandas by implementing a simple project and finding your way around by googling/using the tutorials on how to do operations for your specific project.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use pandas

```py
df = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.csv")
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html

It also lets you easily manipulate rows and a lot more. And there is plenty of tutorials etc. on the web.

Answer (score 0):

The Python standard library has a [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module which is intended for exactly this; you can use either [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) or [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

```py
import csv
def get_numbers():
    with open("students.csv") as fh:
        for row in csv.reader(fh):
           if not row:
               # row is empty; skip
               continue
            # unpack the row into four variables
            name, number, time, duration = row
            print(number)
```